# How can I send a completed Google Form to a user when I submit the form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Form for my Elem. School Principal for Teacher Observations.  She would like to be able to send the completed form to the teacher when she submits the form.

my idea is to somehow add a textbox for the Email address at the end of the form, and when email address is filled, click Submit which will process the form, and send a copy to the recipient email address. I am tryingo to do this via Google's Script editor, but I am not versed in JavaScript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send the filled form to the address of whoever filled it, you can use the "Collect email addresses"  and "response receipts"  functions.

However, if you want to send the email to other users based on a form input field you can use something like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = e.source;
  var response = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var targetEmail = response[response.length].getResponse(); //Gets response for last question

  var htmlResponse = HtmlOutput.createHtmlOutput("<h1>Form Submission:</h1>");

  var questions = form.getItems();
  for (var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
    var answerOfQuestion = response[i].getResponse();
    if (typeof(answerOfQuestion)=="object") {
      var tempAnswer = "<ul>";
      for (var j = 0; j<answerOfQuestion.length; j++) {
        tempAnswer += "<li>"+answerOfQuestion[j].toString()+"</li>";
      }
      tempAnswer += "</ul>";
      answerOfQuestion = tempAnswer;
    }
    htmlResponse.append("<p><b>"+questions[i].getTitle()+":</b> "+answerOfQuestion+"</p>");
  }
  GmailApp.createDraft(targetEmail, 'Form Submission', 'Here is the form results:' + htmlResponse.getContent() , {
    htmlBody: htmlResponse.getContent(),
  }).send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (the gear icon) > General Tab

Select both  "collect email addresses" and "response receipts"

No additional coding necessary.

Comment: But that would only send a reciept to the user filling out the form, not send the form to another user.